# transform sum of exponents

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function, economics

How can we solve the equation for $r$, if $S_i$, $t_i$ are given?

$\sum S_i \cdot \exp(r \cdot t_i) = 0$

I can find approximate numerical solutions, but I would like to have a precise formula. Is it possible?

Can this equation have more then 1 solution? (Surely it may have no solutions at all)

Comment: Substituting $e^r=x$, the problem becomes a degree $t_i$ polynomial, which does not have a "formula" in general.

Comment: $r$, $t_i$, $S_i$ are real numbers, not necessarily integers, $t_i \ge 0$